# PHP - Singleton that returns boolean

Tags: php, static, singleton

I have created a singleton class but I would like the static function that creates the instance to return a boolean value instead of the class object.  It's not working the way I have it setup now, which makes me think that I can only return an instance. In other words, the function does not return true or false; it returns nothing.

```
class CacheMachine {
    private static $_cache;

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function CreateNew(&$cacheFile) {
        if(!isset(self::$_cache)) {
            $object = __CLASS__;
            self::$_cache = new $object();
        }
        if(file_exists($cacheFile)) {
            readfile($cacheFile);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: the function is instantiating the _cache object (self) but it is not returning true or false. It just returns nothing.

Comment: Are you sure readFile() and file_exists() work as intended?  Maybe they break and your code never reaches return statements.

Comment: yes, i have verified that both functions work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Change #1:

```
 private static $_cache = NULL;
```

Change #2:

```
if(self::$_cache === NULL) {
            $object = __CLASS__;
            self::$_cache = new $object();
        }
```

Comment: How is it different from what OP currently has?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding.  I'm trying to return true or false, the instantiation part of the function is working fine.